# Fatal error: Call to a member function addItem() on a non-object

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0, javascript, css, html

when i want to start `klevu search extension` configuration wizard from backend i face this problem.

> a popup window comes up by this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function addItem() on a non-object in app/code/community/VES/VAdmin/Block/Head.php on line 8`

and this is my `head.php`:

```
<?php
class VES_VAdmin_Block_Head extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('vadmin/config/enabled')) return;
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        $headBlock->addItem('link_rel', Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/vadmin_css/index"),'rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"');
        $headBlock->setTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('vadmin/head/default_title'));

        $headerBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('header');
        $headerBlock->setTemplate('ves_vadmin/page/header.phtml');

        /*Disable notification messages*/
        if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('vadmin/header/show_notifications')){
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->unsetChild('notifications');
        }

        if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('vadmin/menu/show_help_link')){
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setTemplate('ves_vadmin/page/menu.phtml');
        }
    }

}
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the content of `head.php` should replaced with this:

```
<?php
class VES_VAdmin_Block_Head extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('vadmin/config/enabled')) return;
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if($headBlock){
            if(in_array('vendors_default',$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles())){
                $headBlock->removeItem('skin_css','ves_vadmin/css/styles.css');
                return;
            }
            $headBlock->addItem('link_rel', Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/vadmin_css/index"),'rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"');
            $headBlock->setTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('vadmin/head/default_title'));
        }
        $headerBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('header');
        if($headerBlock){
            $headerBlock->setTemplate('ves_vadmin/page/header.phtml');
        }
        /*Disable notification messages*/
        if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('vadmin/header/show_notifications')){
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->unsetChild('notifications');
        }

        if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('vadmin/menu/show_help_link')){
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setTemplate('ves_vadmin/page/menu.phtml');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand wanting to answer your own questions, but maybe you could at least describe the problem and the solution instead of just pasting a couple of blobs of code that do not describe anything.